# Reverse Proxy not working on my XAMPP system, how to find the issue?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, xampp

I'm using my mac with XAMPP from [apachefriends](https://www.apachefriends.org/) with the standard configuration.

I want to use a reverse proxy, so I edited the `etc/extra/proxy-html.conf` and added the following:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /my-gateway/ http://interner.server.test/
<Location /my-gateway/>
   ProxyPassReverse /
   ProxyHTMLEnable On
   ProxyHTMLURLMap http://interner.server.test/ /my-gateway/
   ProxyHTMLURLMap / /my-gateway/
</Location>
```

Now when I go to `localhost/my-gateway`, I get the `Error 404 Object not found`.

How to find out why this is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: I don't think you needed a such hard thing as a `ProxyHTMLURLMap` for a simple reverse proxy.

Second: try a `localhost/my-gateway`**/** (with the ending slash!). Does it work?

Third: Here is a surely working config fragment:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName your.proxy.vhost.name
  ProxyRequests Off

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass /my-gateway/ http://interner.server.test/
</VirtualHost>
```

Out of `<VirtualHost` should it work as well. This `<Proxy` directive is also needed.

Comment: Its also not working with the ending slash. I also tried your VirtualHost with the result, when I add the your.proxy.vhost.name to my hosts and then try to open it, I just reach the default localhost page.

Comment: Its working now, I did a other small mistake